# What does integrating a function $f(x)$ with respect to a function $g(x)$?

Tags: integration, terminology

I encountered the following question in my book:

"Integrate $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x^2}$ with respect to $x^2$."

I am a bit confused about what this is supposed to mean.

> In general, what does it mean to integrate a function $f(x)$ with
>   respect to a function $g(x)$?

Comment: My guess is the [Riemann–Stieltjes integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral).

Comment: Probably that book has said what it means at some previous place...

Comment: Off-topic note.  There are 51 users here with username "Chris" or "chris".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you are working with **Stieltjes integration**.
See here for a detailed introduction and examples:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration

http://ocw.nctu.edu.tw/upload/classbfs1209122139184046.pdf

http://www.math.mcgill.ca/labute/courses/255w03/L1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=x^2$ now integrate $(1+u)^\frac{1}{2}du$,

after integrating sub back in $u=x^2$. thats it!

note: theres no need to find relation between $u=x^2$ as in $\frac{du}{dx}=2x$ shouldnt be substituted in.

Comment: can someone verify if my comment is right or wrong :)

Comment: It's correct. Some differential calculus tells you that $d(x^2)=2xdx$. We can then substitute $u = x^2$, making $du = 2xdx$, and your integral results.